# UIToolBar background transparent

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I am trying to place `UIToolBar` in `UINavigationBar`.

```
   UIToolbar* tempFontSizeToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kPaginationToolBarOriginX,kPaginationToolBarOriginY,kPaginationToolBarWidth,kPaginationToolBarHeight)];

    tempFontSizeToolBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

  // create the array to hold the buttons, which then gets added to the toolbar

   NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  [tempFontSizeToolBar setTranslucent:YES];
  UIBarButtonItem *fontSizeBarButtonItem;

  fontSizeBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                         initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:KpreviousPageIcon] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(movePreviousPage:)];

  [buttons addObject:fontSizeBarButtonItem];

  [fontSizeBarButtonItem release];fontSizeBarButtonItem = nil;

  fontSizeBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                         initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:KnextpageIcon] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain  target:self action:@selector(moveNextPage:)];

  [buttons addObject:fontSizeBarButtonItem];

  [fontSizeBarButtonItem release];fontSizeBarButtonItem = nil;

// stick the buttons in the toolbar
  [tempFontSizeToolBar setItems:buttons animated:NO];

  [buttons release];buttons = nil;

  UIBarButtonItem *rightBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tempFontSizeToolBar];

  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarItem;
```

The background color of that `UIToolBar` is the default Blue.
But I need the Toolbar should be in clear color so that the NavigationBar's background image should  appear in that Toolbar also.

Pls suggest me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you're after here, but your code is messy, and I think you can get what you want without so much effort. Anyway, a button item should not have a toolbar as its custom view.

If your goal is to have a 'prev' button on the left and a 'next' button on the right of a UINavigationBar, then you can just set them as the UINavigationItem's `leftBarButtonItem` and `rightBarButtonItem`. No array necessary.

If your goal is to have 'prev' and 'next' adjacent to each other and on the right side of the UINavigationBar, then put them ('next' first) in an array and then use UINavigationItem's `setRightBarButtonItems:animated:`.

In neither case is a UIToolbar necessary. You can couple a UIToolbar with a UINavigationController as per Apple's docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW30). It pops up at the bottom of the screen, perhaps not what you want, but you can set its tint or background image. If you must have the toolbar at top, you can create one and place it there manually, not too hard.

Good luck!

Comment: I am placing toolbar on the top of navigation bar only. What I want is the toolbar should be transparent so that the buttons in the toolbar appears like its placed in navigation bar directly.

Comment: I have already tried those methods. setRightBarButtonItems:animated: is supported only ios 5 .its crashing when run it on version 4.

Comment: So what you're trying to do is mimic `setRightBarButtonItems:animated:` in iOS < 5?

Answer (score 5):

To make a toolbar transparent, use the following:

```
const float colorMask[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] init];
UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(img.CGImage, colorMask)];

[self.toolbar setBackgroundImage:maskedImage forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: This simulates the correct behavior for a different issue that I encountered in iOS 6. [The thread I started on the subject is here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618410/uitoolbar-buttons-with-uiimage-not-entirely-transparent)

Answer (score 2):

set toolbarStyle -1 like this

```
 tools.barStyle = -1; // clear background
```

Comment: This almost works for a UIToolbar on top of a MKMapView as the root view of a UIViewController. The remaining issue is that the toolbar's hairline is still drawn. Here's the fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110883/remove-uitoolbar-hairline-in-ios-7